# I want to Remove all the controls from the "Detail Band", which is a control of "Quick Report" in DELPHI

Tags: delphi, quickreports

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove/ Destroy all the control from quick report detail band](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741170/remove-destroy-all-the-control-from-quick-report-detail-band)

Some user say this is  #"incomplete question" #, but is a very clear question. I want to Remove all the controls from the "Detail Band", which is a control of "Quick Report" in DELPHI.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Do you want to delete all the `QR***` controls at run time? Or at design time?

Comment: Heads up for you. You ask the same question again and again, it gets closed each time, and then the Stack Overflow system bans your account for abuse. So, stop asking questions that are certain to be closed.

Comment: @iManBiglari i want to delete all the QR*** controls at runtime.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If you know DELPHI and QUICKREPORT, then you can easily understand the question.

Comment: No point complaining to me. I'm just telling you how Stack Overflow works. Seriously, if you keep getting questions closed you will get a ban. If you don't like how it is, go to meta.stackoverflow.com and complain there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess something like this would work...

```
for i := DetailBand.ControlCount - 1 downto 0 do
  DetailBand.Controls[0].Free;
```

But I wrote it from memory... Not sure if `QR***` components are `TControl` descendants.

Comment: You're welcome... But it would be appreciated to be more clear in your questions ;-)